# How to reference another project in eclipse for spring 3.1 autowiring?

Tags: web-services, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

I'm using tomcat 6x, spring 3.1 with annotations, cxf 2.2x.  I have a web service project, lets call it wsproject that I have referenced in my main project, lets call that myproject.  I added a project reference for wsproject to myproject using the configurebuildpath in eclipse.  I have everything working and I'm able to go from the main project to the code in the web service project.

Now however, when I try to autowire a service, like myservice from wsproject into the controller, for example, mycontroller in myproject, spring throws this error:

**No matching bean of type [com.service.MyService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}**

I have this in the servlet-context.xml:

```
<annotation-driven />
...
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.myproject" />


 <beans:import resource="classpath*:/WEB-INF/spring/serviceServlet/service-context.xml"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.service.myService"/>  

<beans:bean id="myService" class="com.service.myServiceImpl">
    <beans:property name="myService" ref="myService" />
</beans:bean>
```

and in the MyController class I have:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;
...
```

and on the service I have:

```
 @Service
    @WebService(targetNamespace = "http://...")
    public interface MyService {

//more methods ...
```

but it seems like Spring can't find the other project for some reason.  So when I start up the app I get this error when it loads.  Any ideas what is wrong here?

I did import the project into STS and under the spring explorer I could see that this additional service-context wasn't loaded, so that seems to be the root issue of the problem.  Something isn't configured correctly here.

**Aftermath:**

I wasn't actually pointing to the code in the second project, even though eclipse appeared to be using it. When I removed the original war dependency in maven, compile errors showed up.  So even though eclipse was stopping on breakpoints in the service project, that code wasn't actually running.  I have no idea how that could be, but it was.

So, I removed the service project as a reference to the client project, packaged it up as a war and ran it on tomcat. That solved my referencing issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this a little differently. I would create a spring configuration in both projects. Give it a different name like `service-context.xml`. Then you import the other configuration in your main configuration.

```
<annotation-driven/>
...
<import resource="classpath:service-context.xml"/>
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.myproject"/>
```

This should work if your other project is correctly referenced in the build path configuration.

Anyway if you want to build the project with the dependencies (not only your other project but also the spring dependencies) you really want to take a look into [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) and the m2eclipse plugin. I won't give a full tutorial here because there are already a lot available. I can give you a little aid with your `pom.xml` if you read a little into the basics and decide to use it.

Comment: I had to use this instead: <beans:import resource="classpath*:service-context.xml"/> to avoid a compile time error.  However, it seems to be pointing to that project now as I'm getting errors referencing cxf, which I need to add to my xml file I think.  I'm using maven already, but I'm doing this so I can modify code and debug in the service project that is normally deployed as a war.

Comment: It's still not working, but I think this may be the solution.

Comment: If you use the m2eclipse plugin, Eclipse derives the project configuration from your `pom.xml`. It is even smart enough to recognize if you have one of the dependencies open as project and uses that one instead of the one from your repository. There is no need for manual build path configuration anymore. You can see in the project explorer that the dependency has a folder icon instead of the default one.